# How to avoid Hive cross product?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I have this Hive query that keeps giving me this error:

```
Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[61][bigTable=?] in task 'Map 3' is a cross product
Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[58][bigTable=xxx_table] in task 'Map 3' is a cross product
```

It's a cross product. I have to avoid this because the query takes too long, too much memory

This is the query:

```
WITH view1 AS 
( 
SELECT Max(date) AS max_date
FROM  table1 )
view2 as (
SELECT * FROM table
)
SELECT     
*
FROM view1,view2 
WHERE      
view2.date > view1.max_date
```

Do you have any ideas to solve this WARNING?
I Also tried EXPLAIN query but I can't understand the log

Comment: Since your `view1` query returns a single value there is nothing wrong with cross-joining it to `view2`. The problem is that you use a non-equijoin which results in full scan.

Comment: ok tha's fine, do you have any other possibilities?

Comment: i want to select results from view2 which have date field > than max_date , I have to do some kind of join?

Comment: Thats what I was trying to say - the join might not be the problem. Can you check if a simple `select * from view2 where view2.date > 'some_date'` performs much better?